# Find a formula for $\int ^x _0 [t] \,dt$, $x>0$ real.

Tags: calculus, integration

If $n$ is natural then $$\int_0^n [t] \,dt = \frac{n (n-1)}{2}$$  Find a formula for $\int ^x _0 [t] \,dt$, $x>0$ real.

**Attempt:** $$\int_{0}^{x}[t]dx=\int_{0}^{1}[t]dx+\int_{1}^{2}[t]dx+\int_{2}^{3}[t]dx+\ldots+\int_{n-1}^{n}[t]dx$$ $$=\int_{0}^{1}(0)dx+\int_{1}^{2}1dx+\int_{2}^{3}2dx+\ldots+\int_{n-1}^{n}(n-1)dx$$  $$=0+1+2+3+\ldots+(n-1)$$ $$\implies \int_{0}^{n}[t]dx=1+2+3+\ldots +(n-1)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Am I right? Any hint to solve this problem?

Comment: So given the later usage, you seem to mean $[x]$ is the floor function.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  I edited my attempt. The material's notation was exactly like that. Is it really a floor function? What should I do?

Comment: Maybe break the integral to $\int_0^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\cdots$ and $\int_{\lfloor x\rfloor}^x\cdots$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\int^x_0\lfloor t\rfloor\,dt=\int^{\lfloor x\rfloor}_0\lfloor t\rfloor\,dt +\int^x_{\lfloor x\rfloor}\lfloor t\rfloor\,dt$$

The first integral on the right hand side you can deal with from the attempt in your posting. The remaining integral is easy to calculate. Notice that $\lfloor x\rfloor \leq x<\lfloor x\rfloor +1$. Hence
$$\int^x_{\lfloor x\rfloor}\lfloor t\rfloor\,dt=\lfloor x\rfloor (x-\lfloor x\rfloor)$$

Comment: Can I solve it by discrete sum?

Comment: Do  you mean the first integral in the right hand side? Since $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is an integer, $\int^{\lfloor x\rfloor}_0\lfloor t\rfloor \,dt =\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor(\lfloor x\rfloor -1)}{2}$